# MySQL: ORDER BY significantly slows the query

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by, mariadb

Please consider a table with `queue_name`, `priority` and `message_timestamp` columns.

I'm going to perform the following query:

```
SELECT message_timestamp 
  from queue_messages 
 WHERE queue_name = 'name' 
   AND state = 0 
 ORDER 
    BY message_timestamp DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Here is a compound index for that:

```
CREATE INDEX STATE_QUEUENAME_TIMESTAMP ON `queue_messages` (queue_name, state, message_timestamp);
```

[image]

EXPLAIN shows that index matches the query pretty good (there is no filesort for `ORDER BY`):
[image]

My problem is that without `ORDER BY message_timestamp` I have throughput ~200 prs for this query, but with it ~50 rps!

And more rows in the table, slower the query with `ORDER BY`!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, if  `order by` slows down query performance with big table, this is quite expected.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that **ORDER BY** clause slows down the performance of query as database needs to buffer the intermediary results before giving final output.

**Reason:** A sort operation can not be performed in a pipe-lined fashion. The input has to be read completely before the output can be produced.

The alternative of ORDER BY clause could be **INDEXING**. Indexing keeps your data in an orderly fashion and that's how reduces the overheads for sorting in ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

(In addition to Harshita's answer:)

If you add `INDEX(queue_name, state, message_timestamp)`, then the query will work faster with or without the `ORDER BY`.

Note that *that* composite index handles all of the `WHERE` filtering, and still has the `ORDER BY` column(s) for handling the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

**More**

The `EXPLAIN` shows the use of that index; furthermore it says "Using index".  That means that the index is "covering", which means that the query is performed entirely in the index, and does not need to touch the data.

I would expect the `EXPLAIN` to be the same whether you have the `ORDER BY` or not.  Is it?

What is "prs"?  "rps"?  Perhaps "requests per second"?  Depending on what else is going on and the caching of blocks in the buffer_pool. the variation of 50-200 seems reasonable.  Are there multiple threads reaching for the next item?  Is there an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` that you have not mentioned that 'deletes' the item after it is found?  This will have *more impact* than the `SELECT`; we should really discuss that at the same time.

If you are using a table as a queue, you will eventually hit a situation where it performs poorly.  My mantra on such:  "Don't queue it, just do it".

Comment: Sorry, are you talking about the same index which I described in the question, or I missed something?

Comment: More discussion, plus more questions for you to answer.